# Is it possible to add intents to an agent per session?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a health care chatbot. I want to use same agent for all of my clients. But i want to use same agent for all clients. I want to add intents for each client dynamically . So is there any way i can create intents for each client per session ?

Comment: Can you give an example about why you feel you need to?

Comment: I want to create a healthcare chat bot which can be used by separate clients. I have created a ui to build intents . For each client , the intents will be mostly separate. For example: for gynecologist, the FAQ will be different from general surgeon. So for each client , i want to create intents on api.ai seperately for each session.